# Why b is 10 while var [b=10] = [undefined]?

Tags: javascript

```
var [b=10] = [undefined];
console.log(b)
```

I am wondering how can I split the first line code and why b is equal to 10? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why are you assigning inside a destructuring operator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why b is equal to 10?

This is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_values).

It gets the first element from the Array and assigns it to a new variable called `b`. And only if the value is undefined, it will be given a default value of `10`:

```js
var [b = 10] = [3];
console.log(b); // 3
```

> how can I split the first line code

It could be written like this:

```js
var arr = [undefined],
    b   = arr[0];

if (b === undefined) { b = 10; }

console.log(b); // 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation!